# moment.js error in FromNow()

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I Use moment.js v.2.4.0 and i use this script for calculate how many time has passed

```
$(".time").append(moment.unix({{ mydb|date('U') }}).fromNow());
```

mydb return data like

```
$(".time").append(moment.unix(1387358178).fromNow());
```

---

```
(in my db sql = 2013-12-17 18:30:48)
```

---

and return the right data if my date on my computer is right

if I change my date the difference is wrong. 
Can i make a difference between two date without use time of client computer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Moment is just like the rest of your JavaScript.  If you're running it in your browser, then it will use the timestamp of the computer running the browser when you refer to "now".

If this is important to you, you could consider passing the server's current timestamp and then using the ["Time from X"](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/) functionality, instead of ["Time from now"](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/).

Comment: thanks for reply, maybe these function can help me ? http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/

Comment: I use symfony and this is my script js/twig, i retrieve now of server...thanks
`$(".time").append(moment(moment.unix({{ mydb| date('U')}})).from(moment.unix({{ "now"|date("U")}})));`